# How to create a UDF that returns a complete row in a SuperKey, SubTable database 

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

I would like to know of an example that shows how one can create either a UDF or stored proc that returns a complete row from a Superkey/Subtable in SQL Server database (preferably 2005, but 2008 would be OK).

Specifically, lets imagine that the master table is called `SecurityMaster` which has a `SecurityID` PK. Lets also imagine the last column is the `SecurityType` which defines the table in which more detailed information resides. Lets imagine the `SecurityMaster` table is as follows:

```
SecurityID  Name          Currency   SecurityType
----------  -----------   --------   ------------
1           BP Plc        GBP        Equity
2           MSFT C30 12   USD        EquityOption
3           Greek 6% 20   EUR        Bond
```

Lets further imagine that `EquityOption` table looks like the following

```
SecurityID   PutCall   Strike   Maturity
----------   -------   ------   --------
2            Call      30       Jun 2012
```

Lets also imagine the `Bond` table looks like the following:

```
SecurityID   Coupon   Maturity
----------   ------   -----------
3            0.06     15 Mar 2020
```

I would like a 'method' (be it Proc or UDF) that returns the following joined tables:

```
SELECT * FROM MyFuncOrProc(2)
```

resulting in an output like:

```
SecurityID  Name          Currency   SecurityType   SecurityID   PutCall   Strike   Maturity
----------  -----------   --------   ------------   ----------   -------   ------   --------
2           MSFT C30 12   USD        EquityOption   2            Call      30       Jun 2012
```

The idea here being that I would like to

1. Avoid having a super large `SecurityMaster` sparse table (imagine 50 security types)
2. Having a compact representation of the data requiring less storage space
3. The FK's in the sub tables are on cascading update and delete forcing referential integrity
4. I can supply a dynamic SQL string that is passed to an `Execute` command, but I don't know how to make the row returned available to caller. Imagine that you would like to use the results set to perform another join?
5. If the sub table does not exist (in the case of `Equity`), then it means that the security is completely specified solely by the `SecurityMaster` table

p.s. Please do not close this question until either a full example or a reference to an example has been made available.

p.p.s Someone mentioned this may be able to be done using some of the sys tables or columns, but its not obvious to me how to do this, hence the question.

Many thanks in advance and kind regards,

Bertie.

Answer (score 0):

As long as the number of tables is limited, you can `join` them together:

```
select  *
from    SecurityMaster sm
left join
        EquityOption eo
on      sm.SecurityType = 'EquityOption'
        and sm.SecurityID = eo.SecurityID
left join
        Bond b
on      sm.SecurityType = 'Bond'
        and sm.SecurityID = b.SecurityID
```

It's not unusual for the `SecurityType` column to be omitted altogether.  You can tell whether a security is a Bond if it's `SecurityID` exists in the `Bond` table.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer here, but this example does not make use of the fact that the Table Name to look up is available in sm.SecurityType. If there are 50 sub tables would this be a painful solution to implement? If there is no other way, then I will need to write out 50 joins. I would be really surprised if a more concise (and easy to understand solution for a beginner) is not possible. Many thanks,

Comment: What would you do with the fifty joins?  If it's for a report, move all reportable columns to the master table.  It's OK if this leaves some columns empty.  SQL Server handles empty columns extremely efficiently.

Comment: This type of Select statement would be to feed other Functions, Procs or CTE's. It could also be useful to create a view that aggregates the information. The only thing I dislike with this method is having 49 Subtables showing NULL in the result set along with the required Subtable. Having duplicate Column Names in the results will create a problem for further DML. Is the best way to design the SubTables so that there are no common ColumnNames in the subtable? Many Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Create the simple switch-like proc, like an example.

```
Create proc getFullSecurity
 @SecurityId int
As
Begin
Declare @secType nvarchar(128)

 select @secType =SecurityType
 From securitymaster 
 Where securityid=@securityid

If @sectype = 'equity'
Select join with equity table
Else if @sectype = 'something'
Select join with something
...
End
```

You can prefetch all the needed fields into variables in 1st query - then you need not to join with the main table every next select stms. just use prefetched variables.

Comment: Thanks Oleg for the comment. The only problem with this is that your code would require 50 Elseif statements. If there is no getting around this, then I will have to consider this as a solution, but I would prefer something that uses a dynamic reference to the TableName or something from the Sys table if it is possible. FYI, I received this answer to a similar question. Kind regards, http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/9809/how-to-implement-superkey-sub-key-method-on-cascading-tables

Comment: This will be faster than dynamic query and will keep your procedure cache size relatively low

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE FUNCTION My_Function (@SecurityID Int)
RETURNS TABLE 
AS
RETURN 
(
          select  * 
          from SecurityMaster A
          left join EquityOption B on A.SecurityType = N'EquityOption' and B.SecurityID = A.SecurityID
          left join Bond C on A.SecurityType = N'Bond' and C.SecurityID = A.SecurityID 
          Where A.SecurityID = @SecurityID
)
GO
```